# On Android which way is the best in order for a service to communicate with my app on OnResume

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, xamarin

Im building an app on Xamarin.Android that plays music, for music playing im using a simple service.Even if the app is minimizes the service keeps playing music. For the communication between fragment and service i use MessageBus and i use Application class to store all the data that will be needed from many fragments until the App is closed.

I have a question about which is the best way to update the fragment on the OnResume event that the current playing track has change (after it was minimized and paused):

Im thinking one of those ways:

1) The Application class is storing the current playlists with the track name, resid etc and the current list position, so im thinking on the OnResume event of Application class to update the values and then on the OnResume event of the fragment to take the values from the Application class. But the problem is, how i can be sure that the application OnResume event will fire before fragment's same event?

2) The fragment on OnResume event to send a request to the service to get the current data and then to send them also to the Application class in order to be used from other fragments.

Which approach do you thik is the best?

Also is the same to use

```
public int listpos { get; set;}
```

instead of

```
private int listpos;
```

and to get or set the value with a function? I will have problems with the garbage collector with the public int or some other security issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good approach would be to `Bind` to the service and query it for the details when they are needed. I would not recommend setting any *temporary* data on the `Application` class as this will force you to keep it in sync and can cause problems.

P.S. there is no `OnResume` for the application as a whole.

Comment: message bus and bound service is not the same?which way of storing data do you propose?syncing is not an issue although.

Comment: A `service` is an Android framework component while `MessageBus` is a Xamarin events implementation, they have nothing in common. I'd suggest storing the data relevant to the `Service` **on** the service and if you need it persisted then use `Shared Preferences` or a DB implementation of your choice.

Comment: sorry when i say the same i mean that both are also good. What about data that many other fragments need?extracting this data from sharedpref or database wouldnt cause a delay?

Comment: as far as I know shared prefs use caching also you can implement your own caching mechanism

Comment: thanks for the answers, im trying to achieve the Service + MessageBus  to work as a bounded service here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504311/two-way-communication-send-and-recieve-data-immediately-with-messagebus-doesn but it doesn't working, do you know why?